# RESTClient java program returning unreadable output on console?

Tags: file, rest, multipart, rest-client, jersey-client

```
public class helloWorldClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        helloWorldClient crunchifyClient = new helloWorldClient();

        crunchifyClient.getResponse();
    }

    private void getResponse() {
        try {

            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource2 = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/Downloader/webapi/folder/zipFile");
            ClientResponse response2 = webResource2.accept("application/zip").get(ClientResponse.class);
            if (response2.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response2.getStatus());
            }

            String output2 = response2.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("\n============RESPONSE============");
            System.out.println(output2);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

This program returning an unreadable output. but when I hit that URL "http://localhost:8080/Downloader/webapi/folder/zipFile" in browser "server.zip" file is getting downloaded. 
My question is how can I read that response and write to some folder through java client program?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `InputStream` instead of `String`. Then just do your basic IO.

```
InputStream output2 = response2.getEntity(InputStream.class);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
// do io writing
// close streams
```

Comment: thank you very much peeskillet. I really appreciate your help. I will try this now.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream output2 = response2.getEntity(InputStream.class);

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/mpasala/Downloads/demo.zip"));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = output2.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            output2.close();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Done!");
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet .